# Fixed-Effects model and Entities with No Variation

Tags: fixed-effects-model

Suppose I am interested in the effect of some treatment $T_{it}$.

I consider the following simple fixed effects model:

$y_{it}=b_0+b_1T_{it}+\gamma_i +e_{it}$ where $\gamma_i$ is individual-level fixed effects.

- For some group of individuals, I observed two situations: with and
  without treatments.
- For the other group of people, they didn't get any treatment in
  entire sample period.
- If I include the group of people who didn't get any shock in the
  regression, my estimate $b_1$ seems to shrink to zero.

Could you explain why?

Comment: Just to confirm: you are using a fixed effect model with fixed effect transformation? I.e. not a random effect model?

Comment: Yes, this is not a random effect model.

Comment: This is strange. I think your estimate shouldn't change at all.

Comment: That is exactly what I thought..